# Angular2 - Push checked value to array on check

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that receives an object of employee records and displays them in a table. Each record has a checkbox that allows you to "select" the employee to be included in the next process.

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of importResults" >
 <td>
  <input type="checkbox"
         value="{{ i.QID }}"
         attr.data-employeename="{{ i.PreferredName }} {{ i.LastName }}"
         [checked]="isSelected" />
  </td>
  <td>{{ i.PreferredName }} {{ i.LastName }}</td>
</tr>
```

In this component, I created an array `selectedEmployees = [];` and my goal is that when I click a checkbox, its value is pushed to the array, as well as when I uncheck it, the value is removed from the array.

I tried using `ngModel` for `2 way binding` but because this data doesn't have an initial checked value in the object, I wasn't able to get that working correctly.

Is `ngModel` the best way to achieve this? Perhaps I was just going about it the wrong way.

I tried following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166443/angular2-push-values-to-array-on-checkbox-selected) but typescript threw an error saying `.entries` was not valid. It may have been for an older version of angular?

Comment: What about just building the list of checked employees when moving on to the next process? It's going to be a lot easier.

Comment: @Steveadoo I suppose that would be an option. Still trying to figure out the whole communication between components aspect so getting those values in the next process (a sibling component) will be what I will need to figure out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can store the isSelected property in the "i" variable. Then just do a `importResults.filter(i => i.isSelected)` to only select the selected employees. You can store that result on a field in your component and pass that field into the sibling component. You will need to use ngModel for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `click` event to the checkbox and pass it to a function to handle add or remove.

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of importResults" >
 <div>
  <input type="checkbox"
         value="{{ i.QID }}"
         (click)="change(i)"/>
   <span>{{ i.PreferredName }} {{ i.LastName }}</span>
  </div>
</div>

<p> Selected Employee: {{selectedEmployees | json}} </p>
```

component.ts:

```
export class SelectFormExample {
  selectedEmployees = [];

  showSiblingComp = false;

  importResults = [
    {QID: "1", PreferredName: 'Steak', LastName: "Pizza"},
    {QID: "2", PreferredName: 'Cheese', LastName: "Burger"},
    {QID: "3", PreferredName: 'Chicken', LastName: "Panini"}
  ];

  constructor(private service: SharedService){

  }

  change(obj){

    let updateItem = this.selectedEmployees.find(this.findIndexToUpdate, obj.QID));

    let index = this.selectedEmployees.indexOf(updateItem);

    console.log(index);

    if(index > -1){
      this.selectedEmployees.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else{
      this.selectedEmployees.push(obj);
    }

    this.service.setList(this.selectedEmployees);

  }

  findIndexToUpdate(obj) { 
        return obj.QID === this;
  }
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Iib3XZeu27AqUFBFzRhW?p=preview)

I have extended the demo to include sharing the `selectedEmployees` with a sibling component via shared service.

Comment: This gave me some typescript errors saying that `.checked` isn't a property.

Comment: Probably, can't find the element by id. Just ensure `id` for input field is set to `id="checkbox{{ i.QID }}"` or if you have a different id, that's what being used in the function. It's working in the demo :S.

Comment: Weird, this is a pre-compile error so it has not even checked the HTML template yet. I have it added in there correctly though. `Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

Comment: I have updated the answer, not using `id` or `getElementById` anymore. See, if that helps :)

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly! One small ask.. I also have a "check all" box in my table header. How could include this so that it trigger this event on all boxes? `<th><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" (change)="isSelected = !isSelected"></th>`

Comment: For that you will have to add a property in your object to get access to each checkbox, since you can't access them using `ElememntId`. Then a function can take care of selecting and deselecting all options. Something like this https://plnkr.co/edit/LJifj1KofV0TzCJaF5np?p=preview