# On click one checkbox selects all Why?

Tags: angular

> Hi i'm designing checbox with multiple values but when i click one
>   checkbox it selects all

```
 <div [ngClass] = "{'form-group': true}">
              <label>{{initialInformationDetails.objectiveOfUtilisingServiceText}}</label>
             <div>
                <label *ngFor = "let objective of initialInformationDetails.objectiveOfUtilisingService">
                <input type="checkbox" 
                       name="objective"
                       formControlName = "objectiveOfUtilisingServiceControl"
                       value="{{objective.value}}" 
                       [(ngModel)]="userInfo.objective"/> {{objective.value}}
                </label> 
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: See this question, its pretty close to what you are trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45085453/5556177

Comment: You have a reactive form? it's discouraged to use it together with ngModel. I'm wondering at the formcontrolname, since if you want to have several checked boxes, it won't work with a form control, since it can only capture one value, I'd say you want a formarray.

Comment: Hey, how did it go with the answers? Did either help you or do you need further help? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [checked] instead of [(ngModel)]

```
<div [ngClass] = "{'form-group': true}">
              <label>{{initialInformationDetails.objectiveOfUtilisingServiceText}}</label>
             <div>
                <label *ngFor = "let objective of initialInformationDetails.objectiveOfUtilisingService">
                <input type="checkbox" 
                       name="objective"
                       formControlName = "objectiveOfUtilisingServiceControl"
                       value="{{objective.value}}" 
                       [checked]="userInfo.objective"/> {{objective.value}}
                </label> 
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i need to save checked data to save is it possible without [(ngModel)]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a reactive form, utilize it. It is discouraged to use `ngModel` with a reactive form. In the `ReactiveFormsModule` the `ngModel` directive is not even included.

Since you have several checkboxes, you should use a `FormArray` to capture the values. We could call that FormArray `objectiveOfUtilisingServiceControls`.

Then we have a method for the adding or removing of the items to the form array. We have a change event in the template, in which we pass the boolean of the checkbox, meaning if it's checked or not, as well as the actual item we want to add to the form array:

```
(change)="onChange(objective.value, $event.target.checked)"
```

The `onChange` method would look like this:

```ts
onChange(value:string, isChecked: boolean) {
  let objectiveOfUtilisingServiceControls = 
               <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.objectiveOfUtilisingServiceControls;

  if(isChecked) {
    objectiveOfUtilisingServiceControls.push(new FormControl(value));
  } else {
    let index = 
      objectiveOfUtilisingServiceControls.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == value)
    objectiveOfUtilisingServiceControls.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

Where we either push a new `FormControl` to the form array, or if it's unchecked we remove the form control from the form array.

Since you have some value that is prechecked, we also need to initially add that one in the form array. We can do it after we have built the form, which can look like this: (`fb` is referring to `Formbuilder`)

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  // build form
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    objectiveOfUtilisingServiceControls: this.fb.array([])
  });

//iterate and check which object matches the with the value in 'userInfo.objective'
for (let obj of this.initialInformationDetails.objectiveOfUtilisingService) {
    if (obj.value == this.userInfo.objective) {
      this.onChange(obj.value, true)
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

And as for the prechecked value in the template, just use `[checked]`:

```html
<label *ngFor="let objective of initialInformationDetails.objectiveOfUtilisingService">
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(objective.value, $event.target.checked)"
        [checked]="userInfo.objective == objective.value"/> {{objective.value}}
</label>
```

and when you submit the form, you have all values of the form in `myForm.value`, just change `myForm` to the actual form name you have.