# How to get checked checkboxes values in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the values of checked checkboxes and put them into a strig , that string will be used in my api.
I want to get the values once the checkbox is checked and retrieve the value if that checkbox is unchecked.

```
   <div *ngFor="let x of groupesTable">
       <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="group" (change)=""> 
       {{x.nom_groupe | uppercase}}
  </div>
```

I've no idea how to do that or what method should I use in typescript.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is an update

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let x of groupesTable">
               <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">
               <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" nom="check1"  [value]= "x.nom_groupe"
               name="x.nom_groupe" (change)="callMe($event, x.nom_groupe)"  [(ngModel)]="grp">{{x.nom_groupe | uppercase}}
               </label>
</div>
```

and in the .ts file i did this

```
 callMe(event, nom) {
if (event.target.checked) 
  {
    console.log(nom);
    this.nomgrps=this.nomgrps+nom.toUpperCase()+" ";
    console.log(this.nomgrps); 
  }
  else {
    console.log(this.nomgrps);
  }}
```

But this also doesn't work , i don't know why it checks all the checkboxes while i only check one.

Answer (score 4):

It checks and unchecks all the boxes together because all your formControls are bound to the same variable: `grp`. Either create an array of new form models which you can use to get the checkboxes which are checked or you use the object in the loop by adding a new property `checked` on it on the fly.

Something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of groupesTable">
      <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="x.checked" (change)="foo()"> 
      {{x.nom_groupe | uppercase}}
</div>


foo() {
  let checkedStrings = this.groupesTable.reduce((acc, eachGroup) => {
    if (eachGroup.checked) {
      acc.push(eachGroup.nom_groupe.toUpperCase())
    }
    return acc
  }, []).join(" ")

  console.log(checkedStrings);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dj95pg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @MedAnis please notice the extra `checked` key being created under the objects in `groupesTable`. If you don't want that then have an array in your ts which will hold one variable per object of the groupsTable, each variable will now be used to bind to each of the check boxes

Answer (score 0):

Med, a checkbox can get only two values: true or false. So you need an array to store the values. If your groupesTable is an array of objects, you can use the own object "groupesTable". else you need store the values in an array.

```
<div *ngFor="let x of groupesTable">
       <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="x.checked"> 
       {{x.nom_groupe | uppercase}}
</div>

//or
//declare in your .ts
checkes:boolean[]=[]
//and your .html
<div *ngFor="let x of groupesTable;let i=index">
      <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="checkes[i]"> 
       {{x.nom_groupe | uppercase}}
</div>
```

When you want to get the values selected you only need use the array. Make a function

if your groupesTables is an array of object,e.g.

```
[{id_groupe:0,nom_groupe:'...'},{id_groupe:1,nom_groupe:'...'},..]
```

Your function can look like as

```
getValuesChecked()
{
  return groupesTable.filter(x=>x.checked).map(x=>x.id_groupe).join(",")  
}
//or 
getValuesChecked()
{
  return groupesTable.filter((x,index)=>this.checkes[index])
       .map(x=>x.id_groupe).join(",")  
}
```

You can call to the function each change (using ngModelChange) but you can simply call the function before submit the data

Answer (score -1):

Use ngModelChange:

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of groupesTable">
   <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="group" (ngModelChange)="change(obj, $event)"> 
   {{x.nom_groupe | uppercase}}
</div>
```

typescript:

```
public inputs = [];

change(obj: any, check: boolean){
    if(check) this.inputs.push(obj);
    else this.inputs = arrayRemove(this.inputs, obj);

    displayCheckBoxes();
}

displayCheckBoxes(){
    this.inputs.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element);
    });
}

arrayRemove(arr, value) {
    return arr.filter(function(ele){
        return ele != value;
    });
}
```

Comment: no this doesn't work , it checks or unchecks all the options when i only check onecheckbox , plus what i really want to do is to concatenate the values of the checked checkboxes

Comment: why don't you just add the obj to an array in the change function if `check == true` or remove if `check == false` and then get all the array elements?

Comment: I actually have no idea how to do that , plus the elements that i'm displaying are provided from a database

Comment: I have updated the typescript code to show you an example of what I mean. The displayed data provided from the database shouldnt affect the code because it takes the html value from the checkbox

Comment: I'm going to try the code that you provided , but it checks all the checkboxes when i only check one , do you have any idea why is that ? @David

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098169/on-click-one-checkbox-selects-all-why